# Проблема с выводом массива в итераторе. Пропускается элемент с нулевым индексом

Tags: java, массивы, итераторы

Суть состоит в том, что в main мы можем задавать шаг для итерации через  iterator.changeSpeed(...). Итератор перебирает и выводит элементы массива. Проблема состоит в том, что какое бы значение для шага мы не вводили, всегда будет пропускаться 0-й элемент.

```
        Harmonica harmonica = new Harmonica(originPointList);            
        PointIterator iterator = harmonica.iterator(); //вывод списка точек в консоль
        iterator.changeSpeed(1);
        System.out.println("List's length: " + harmonica.getPointsListLength() + "\n");

        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());               
        }
```

Я знаю, что проблема состоит в этой части кода (что указана ниже), а именно в строке `return pointList.get(index += speed)`, т.к. к index сначала прибавляется указанное значение шага, а только потом возвращается index. Если в условии указать `index =+ speed`, то программа зациклится на выводе элемента с 1-м индексом.

```
public PVTPoint next() {
        if(this.hasNext()) {
            return pointList.get(index = + speed);
        }else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }
```

Мой вопрос состоит в том, как решить этот момент, чтобы сначала возвращался index, а только потом прибавлялся новый шаг и не пропускался элемент с 0-м индексом?

Comment: потому что `=+` и `+=` - не одно и то же

Comment: @timur, я знаю, просто суть в том, что мне нужно, чтобы get() каким-то образом сначала возвращал значение index, а только потом прибавлялся speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (this.hasNext()) {
        PVTPoint result = pointList.get(index);
        index += speed;
        return result;
    } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант, при котором индекс будет рассчитываться каждый раз:

```
public PVTPoint next() {
    if (this.hasNext()) {
        return pointList.get((speed - 1) * index + index++);
    } else {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```